# Не брать значение после определённых символов

Tags: python, строки, методы, split

Нужно разделить строку `https://sun9-65.userapi.com/impf/JetMttw4tKqGGrPmAy_u00gKPdWhq79dT18gp-Q/cvM38hAo.jpg?size=604x483` так, чтобы получилось:
`cvM38hAo.jpg`.

Метод `split` делит строку только одним символом, на выходе получается `cvM38hAo.jpg?size=604x483`.

Нужно также убрать всё, что идёт после `?`.

Comment: разделите ещё раз по символу `?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше всего воспользоваться соответствующими инструментами для парсинга URL и путей:

```
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = "https://sun9-65.userapi.com/impf/JetMttw4tKqGGrPmAy_u00gKPdWhq79dT18gp-Q/cvM38hAo.jpg?size=604x483"

res = os.path.basename(urlparse(url).path)
```

результат:

```
In [309]: res
Out[309]: 'cvM38hAo.jpg'
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант от MaxU предпочтительней, но для общего сведения вот еще решение через регулярки:

```
import re
a = "https://sun9-65.userapi.com/impf/JetMttw4tKqGGrPmAy_u00gKPdWhq79dT18gp-Q/cvM38hAo.jpg?size=604x483"

res = re.match(r".+/(.+)\?", a).group(1)
```

res:

```
'cvM38hAo.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще один способ для ознакомления, в котором не используются какие-либо модули.

```
def url2filename(url: str, extensions: tuple=(".jpg", ".png", ".gif")):
    """Ищет имя (единственного) файла в url по его расширению."""
    for ext in extensions:
        index = url.find(ext) # index - индекс первого символа ext в url
        if index == -1:
            continue
        result = url[:index + len(ext)]
        while index > -1:
            index -= 1
            if result[index] in "/\\?%*:|":
                result = result[index + 1:]
                break
        return result
print(url2filename("https://sun9-65.userapi.com/impf/JetMttw4tKqGGrPmAy_u00gKPdWhq79dT18gp-Q/cvM38hAo.jpg?size=604x483"))
```

Comment: Принципиальное отличие вашего способа от двух других в том, что вы ищите подстроку с именем графического файла, причем первую попавшуюся. на таком примере ваш код будет работать неправильно: "https://sun9-65.userapi.com/my.jpgs/JetMttw4tKqGGrPmAy_u00gKPdWhq79dT18gp-Q/cvM38hAo.jpg?size=604x483"